# How to get schema along with kafka topic information from kafka client?

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

I can see that in the java client we can get a list of topics and their configs using `Admin.describeTopics(Collection)`. Is there a way to also get the schemas back from that call?

I am new to kafka and not sure how to get the topic information and schemas from the registry and tie them back together. Any tips or documentation is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kafka knows nothing about schemas and doesn't store them as part of the topic.

You can use `CachedSchemaRegistryClient` from `io.confluent:kafka-schema-registry-client`

https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/develop/api.html